# Нужно привязать клавишу к программе

Tags: python

Пишу таймер на Пайтоне. Хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии конкретной клавиши время перестало идти.

Часть кода:

```
if a == cnty:
print("Отсчёт пошёл. Чтобы остановить его, нажмите Enter")
while a == cnty:
    sec = 0
    while sec == sec:
        keyboard.add_hotkey('enter', lambda: sec != sec and print("Таймер остановлен"))
        sec += 1
        time.sleep(1)
        print(sec)
```

При нажатии Enter таймер всё равно продолжает идти. Как правильно написать программу?

Answer (score 0):

Для вашей задачи можно использовать `keyboard.is_pressed` Вот пример как можно сделать вашу программу:

```
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("enter"):
        print("Таймер остановлен"))
        sec += 1
        time.sleep(1)
        print(sec)
```

Просто замените мой цикл на свой. Кстати
`keyboard.is_pressed` возразщает `True` если кнопка нажата и `False` если не нажата.
А вот уже готовый код:

```
if a == cnty:
print("Отсчёт пошёл. Чтобы остановить его, нажмите Enter")
while a == cnty:
    sec = 0
    while sec == sec:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("enter"):
            print("Таймер остановлен")
            sec += 1
            time.sleep(1)
            print(sec)
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: sec != sec неправильное выражение, например sec = 31, 31 не может быть НЕ равен 31. 31 будет всегда равен 31